# How to check SSL is enabled or not in Jboss AS 7

Tags: ssl, jboss7.x

Does anybody know how to check SSL is enabled or disabled in Jboss AS7?

I just follow this guide https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/SSL+setup+guide to setup SSL, now I want to know any ways (script or java) to check SSL status after configuration.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of following to know whether `ssl` is enabled or not.

```
String sslID = (String)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session");
```

Comment: Can you explain more details about your comment?

Comment: yes, you can check the ssl session id from the request object. If your Jboss AS7 have enable the SSL then your request object will have the attribute.

Comment: Can you check this via JNDI?